# Read Very Large and Dynamic Nested JSON file in JAVA

Tags: java, json, string, buffer, heap-memory

I have a huge json file (++500mb) consists of dynamic structure of nested json file. This json was extracted to file using 'json.dump' in python.
My problem is how can i read this huge json file with buffer method?

Since if i read all the strings in the same runtime it throws java heap error.
My thought is i want to read the json each record and then parse it, after that continue to next record, parse it, and so on. But how can i know which one is the end of one json record. Because i can't find the seperator between each json record.

Any suggestion? Please ask if something is not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can't simply increase the heap space size with `-Xmx` you can switch your JSON reading logic to use a SAX JSON parsers e.g. [RapidJSON](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html) or [Jackson Streaming API](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi). Instead of storing the entire JSON body in the memory those libraries will emit an event for each encountered JSON construct:

```
{
  "hello": "world",
  "t": true
  ...
}
```

will produce below when using RapidJSON:

```
StartObject()
Key("hello", 5, true)
String("world", 5, true)
Key("t", 1, true)
Bool(true)
...
EndObject()
```

Comment: But can it be used for the unstrucured and dynamic json? I mean, doesn't SAX JSON parser like jackson need us to provide the structure or the scheme of our json? Since i want to get all the json objects inside my json files and they're all unstructured.